Ubuntu 24.04.1 stuck at "Copying files" Oct 07 13:16:50 ubuntu subiquity_log.3691[6285]: finish: cmd-apt-config: SUCCESS: curtin command apt-config
I am installing Ubuntu on an existing machine which had windows, my Hard disk had 3 partitions C, E & D. I formatted C and created all the relevant partitions for Linux in this space. Now my installation is stuck in Copying Files with the above command in CMD being the last, the installation started at 13:10 and this command ran at 13:16, now its already 14:30 no commands have been run and it continuously saying copying files but has not moved forward. What could be the issue?

This question is similar to: Ubuntu 20.04 runs OK from USB but it takes too long to install on the HDD. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
